# How to make my "phone" field just like Google Signup Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, country-codes

i have field for "`Phone Number`" what i need to do is that to make it like the below image.default will be the user current location country code

[image]

when i click into it so it opens like this[image]

Note : I do not need Country flags and it's jQuery Mobile Site.
Can anyone Provide me the jsfiddle ?

Comment: SO is not for requesting code, please revise your question and show some effort.
My guess it's some sort of combo-select box.

Comment: @AleksandrM i have tried this            $("#countrycode").live('change',function(){
            var code = $(this).val();
            if(code.length){
                $("#phone").val(code);
            }
        });

Comment: @AleksandrM and what i am talking about is not DROP DOWN thats why i have put question.idk why downvote++ ??

Comment: @FawadGhafoor: Because it is not what you call a good question and you not showing any kind of effort.

Comment: i know that someone is definitely looking for clever solution, and i found one: http://jackocnr.com/intl-tel-input.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a jquery skinned drop-down list with country names and simply using the selected option to add the country code to your textbox?

UPDATE: It **is** actually a dropdown. Consider the jQuery TimePicker plugin snippet below:

```
// some default cars
    var newHTML = '';
    var $t = $(this);

    // calculate the offsets
    var height = this.height() + 1;
    var width = this.outerWidth();

    // generate our html dropdown
    var timeMargins = ['00', '15', '30', '45'];
    newHTML += ' <select style="position: absolute; left:0;top:' + height + 'px; width: ' + width + 'px;" size="7">'
    for (var h = params.minHour; h <= params.maxHour; h++)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < timeMargins.length; i++)
        {
            if (h == params.maxHour && timeMargins[i] >= params.maxMinute)
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                var newhour = "" + h;
                var v = (newhour.length == 1 ? '0' : '') + h + ':' + timeMargins[i];
                newHTML += '<option>' + v + '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    newHTML += '</select>';

    var id = this.attr('id');
    var newid = id + '-container';

    // wrap the target in the div
    $t.wrap('<div id="' + newid + '" style="position: relative; display: inline;"></div>');
    $t.after(newHTML);
```

It should help you understand how the dropdown is created via jQuery/javascript.

Comment: i know that all i just need it like the google SignUp page BECAUSE THAT IS NOT DROP DOWN.thats why i have put question.

Comment: I updated my answer to show an example of how such a dropdown could be added to a textbox. It's a time picker script, but it could be easily modifield to be a country-code picker.